# Using split() separate strings and Ints in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to use the `split()` method to separate the strings and Integers from an array but cannot get it work.

I get the Index Of Bounds Exception at line 7 where it is says `surname = list[1];` and have no idea why?

What I am trying to eventually do is split each element and get the average of the Integers so the first line of text in the file would read Mildred Bush 45 65 45 67 65 and my new line of text that I write to a new file would read Bush, Mildred: Final score is x.xx.

I have tried this for a long while now and can just simply not get it to work.

My code:

```
public static void splitTest()
{
String forename, surname, tempStr, InputFileName, OutputFileName, nextLine;
    int sum = 0;
    float average;
    //forename = "Mildred";
    //surname = "Bush";
    nextLine = "";
    tempStr = "";

    String[] list = tempStr.split(" ");
    String[] list = new String[12];
    forename = list[0];
    surname = list[1];
    int[] scores = new int[5];
    scores[0] = Integer.parseInt(list[2]);
    scores[1] = Integer.parseInt(list[3]);
    scores[2] = Integer.parseInt(list[4]);
    scores[3] = Integer.parseInt(list[5]);
    scores[4] = Integer.parseInt(list[6]);

    FileReader fileReader = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    PrintWriter printWriter = null;
    clrscr();

    // Prompt user for input filename
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the file that is to be READ (e.g. details.txt) : ");
    InputFileName = Genio.getString();

    // Prompt user for output filename
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the file that is to be WRITTEN TO (e.g. newDetails.txt) : ");
    OutputFileName = Genio.getString();
    try {
        // Open input file
        fileReader = new FileReader(InputFileName);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader); 

        // Open output file
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(OutputFileName);
        printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStream);

        // Read a line
        tempStr = bufferedReader.readLine();

        // While there are lines in the input file
        while (tempStr != null) {
            String[] list;
            list = tempStr.split(" ");
            surname = list[0];
            forename = list[1];
            int[] scores = new int[5];
            scores[0] = Integer.parseInt(list[2]);
            scores[1] = Integer.parseInt(list[3]);
            scores[2] = Integer.parseInt(list[4]);
            scores[3] = Integer.parseInt(list[5]);
            scores[4] = Integer.parseInt(list[6]);

            for(int i=0; i < scores.length; i++){
                sum = sum + scores[i];

                average = (float)sum/scores.length;
                // Print it to screen
                System.out.println(tempStr);

                // Write it to the output file + a new-line
                printWriter.write(tempStr +"\n");

                // Read a line
                tempStr = bufferedReader.readLine();

                System.out.println("\n\nYOUR NEW FILE DATA IS DISPLAYED ABOVE!\n\n");
                pressKey();

                // Close the input file
                bufferedReader.close();

                // Close the output file
                printWriter.close();   
            }
        }
```

Where it says `Genio`, this a class that deals with user input. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is

```
String[] list = tempStr.split(" ");
String[] list = new String[12];
```

Change it to

```
String[] list = tempStr.split(" ");
```

remove the `String[] list = new String[12];`

Here you were splitting the sting and then when you do `String[] list = new String[12];` you were overwriting the value of the array !

Also

```
while (tempStr != null) {
```

is an endless loop. You will need to fix that..

As posted in the comments `tempStr = "";` when you choose to split it this will give you a string with length 1 you should change this to `tempStr = "Mildred Bush 45 65 45 67 65";`

---

## Edit :

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    String forename, surname, tempStr, InputFileName, OutputFileName, nextLine;
    int sum = 0;
    float average;
    nextLine = "";
    tempStr = "Mildred Bush 45 65 45 67 65";

    String[] list = tempStr.split(" ");
    forename = list[0];
    surname = list[1];
    int[] scores = new int[5];
    scores[0] = Integer.parseInt(list[2]);
    scores[1] = Integer.parseInt(list[3]);
    scores[2] = Integer.parseInt(list[4]);
    scores[3] = Integer.parseInt(list[5]);
    scores[4] = Integer.parseInt(list[6]);
    System.out.println("Forename : "+ forename);
    System.out.println("Surname : "+ surname);
    System.out.print("Scores : ");
    for(int eachInt : scores){
        sum+=eachInt;
        System.out.print(eachInt+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Average : " + sum/scores.length);
}
```

Output:

```
Forename : Mildred
Surname : Bush
Scores : 45 65 45 67 65 
Average : 57
```

Comment: won't work because tempStr is declared as an empty string.  So if it's split by a space, the length of the resulting array is only 1.

Comment: @La-comadreja I assume that is just to depict the problem it is not actually that.

Comment: I tried that but I am still getting the error. One other things, where I parse the integers, should this be at the beginning or in the while loop?

Comment: You want it in or after the while loop. In general, code executes from top to bottom, you'll want the values to be entered and assigned before parsing through all of them. I would advise running the code with debugging and stepping through each line to see how it's working.